# UTF-8 when running management commands from script

Tags: django, django-manage.py

I am using this command to dump data

```
py -Xutf8 manage.py dumpdata app.ModelName --indent 4 --format=json --output app/fixtures/data.json
```

which works perfectly fine.
However when I try to run the command in script

```
management.call_command(
    "dumpdata",
    indent=4,
    format="json",
    output=os.path.join(path, "app//fixtures//data.json"),
    verbosity=1,
)
```

It ends up with this error:

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: Unable to serialize database: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: character maps to <undefined>
```

I have tried something like [this](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10625/) yet it still doesn't work. Any solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at it in a hex editor (free ones are available online, or use Linux vim, etc.) and make sure the MSb is 0.  "smart quotes" (left & right leaning, 0x93) in particular show up in automatically in Microsoft stuff (Notepad will not remove these chars).  Use ASCII (a sub-set of UTF-8--first row in encoding table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Encoding (note also that not all bit patterns are legal)) only.

This might help too, but it goes beyond what we are talking about here:
https://www.charset.org/charsets/iso-8859-1